# Write the expression for $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I have a confusion regarding how to go about solving the following question:

Suppose you are invited to play a game where your earnings are given by multiplying the outcome of rolling a fair die ($Z$) with tossing a fair coin ($X$). You have to pay $\$5$ each time you want to play this game.

Let 
$Y$ = net earnings,
$Z$ = outcome of dice ($1,2,\ldots,6$),
$X$ = outcome of coin ($X$ equals $1$ if heads and $2$ if tails)

- Write $Y$ in terms of $X$ and $Z$

This comes out as $Y = XZ-5$ (I think)

- Write the expression for $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$. What is the expected earnings if
  we know the coin landed tail
- What is your expected earning from playing this game? Answer
  without making a probability distribution for $Y$.

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can you find an answer yourself for the question in the first bullet? Do an effort and edit.

Comment: Numerical values of coin toss is a little arbitrary!.  I can fix X to be 0 for tails and 1 for head and the net earnings ' equation is different.  Has the problem not given what the numerical outcome of X?

Comment: This is the entirety of the question I am afraid and it has me confused as to how I should go about it

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the fact that dice roll and coin toss are independent, after that (and the fact that for independent variables $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X) \cdot \mathbb{E}(Y)$) it's rather trivial.

Comment: I am afraid I still do not understand your answer correctly

Comment: An answer will be helpful

Comment: well, you wrote Y in terms of X and Z correctly, now $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[XZ - 5] = \mathbb{E}[XZ] - 5 = $(because X and Z are independent) $\mathbb{E}[X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[Z] - 5.$

$\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ will be a function of expected value of Y given X. So you have to define a function g(x) that for a given coin toss result gives expected value of the whole experiment. So you "calculate E[Y] using x", where x is a constant, not a random variable. $g(x) = \mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \mathbb{E}[xZ - 5] = $(x is a number, it's important here that X and Z are independent)$ x \cdot \mathbb{E}[Z] - 5$.

Comment: another simple way to go about $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ without using independence is just writing explicitly writing the $\mathbb{E}[Y|x=1]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|x=2]$

Comment: This was really helpful, i had in mind that x will be a constant but your explanation has made it quite clear to me. Thanks a lot I really appreciate you taking out time to explain it neatly